# Deducing probability of an event, when opponent's type is uncertain

Tags: probability, game-theory, decision-theory

Suppose, two players I and II, given a state space of three states$\{a,b,c\}$ with a common prior, $p(a) = p(b) =p(c)  =1/3$, are endowed with two partitions of state space, $\mathscr{P}_\text{I} = \{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$ and $\mathscr{P}_\text{II} = \{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$. State space, prior probability distribution on state space, the information structure, $\mathscr{P}_{\text{I}}$ and $\mathscr{P}_{\text{II}}$ are [common knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge) to I and II.

I and II's objectives are to deduce the posterior probability of an event $E $ as accurate as possible. They announce his own posterior probability in an alternating fashion.

Let's assume the state $b$ is obtained and $E = \{b\}$. At the first stage, I will announce $p(E) = 1/2$, because given his partition, he can't distinguish $a$ and $b$ when $a$ or $b$ actually happens. At the second stage II will announce $p(E) = 1$, because he can deduce from I's announcement that the actual state must be $a$ or $b$, and he knows that from his own partition the actual state is $b$ or $c$. at the third stage, I will announce $p(E) = 1$ too.

If II's objective is to make I's posterior probability as **inaccurate** as possible and such objetive is common knowledge. I's estimation of $P(E)$ will be $1/2$, because I can always turn a deaf ear to II to guarantee the result is not worse than that, and II can always choose to announce a random number from $[0,1]$ to make sure I's estimation of $E$ is not more accurate than that.

Here's my question. What if II's objective type is uncertain to I. To be precise, it's a common knowledge that there is a 50/50 chance II is a honest type or a dishonest type in the eyes of I. What are best strategies for I and II?

Comment: *given a state space of four states {a,b,c}*... is almost pataphysics.

Comment: @Did:Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different types of player II have to be encoded in the state space, the answer will depend on the specific encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't quite follow it. Do you mean there's more than one way to "encode in the state space "which may result in different answers. My naive attempt is to add one dimension of player II's type.$\mathscr{P}_{\text{I}}$ and $\mathscr{P}_{\text{II}}$ will be turned into something like$ \{\{a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2\},\{c_1,c_2\}\}$ and $\{\{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \{b_1,c_1\},\{b_2,c_2\}\}$.

Comment: It depends on what you want. You seem to want to hae the type of the player be chosen independently, which is one of many possibilities.